# Formula to calculate 20 days moving average of stocks in power BI

Tags: powerbi, stock

I need help to calculate 20 days moving average of stocks in Power BI ? I need the formula. I have 6 months data of the stock market with the following fields:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvFfT.png)

I tried using this formula but it shows the 20 day moving average value the same as close price's values

20-day Moving Average =
CALCULATE(
AVERAGE(Table[CLOSE]),
FILTER(
ALL(Table[TIMESTAMP]),
Table[TIMESTAMP] <= MAX(Table[TIMESTAMP]) &&
Table[TIMESTAMP] >= MAX(Table[TIMESTAMP]) - 19
)
)

This is the output I am getting:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdkTy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Give Table name inside ALL filter, not TIMESTAMP column.

```
20-day Moving Average = CALCULATE( AVERAGE(Table[CLOSE]), FILTER( ALL('Table'), Table[TIMESTAMP] <= MAX(Table[TIMESTAMP]) && Table[TIMESTAMP] >= MAX(Table[TIMESTAMP]) - 19 ) )
```